# How do I change my code from looking like this to be better formatted?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Currently writing a bot in discord py
Game that i have created is Hangman

I recently had a problem of not being able to have two players playing at the same time. So I learned that making a dict and storing variables for each player would allow me to have multiple games running at the same time. However my code ended up being a bit messy. What are some ways I could change this?

```
        if ctx.author not in self.dictionaries:
            self.dictionaries[ctx.author] = {
                ctx.author: {
                "self.player": ctx.author.id,
                "self.chosen_word" : "",
                "self.guessed_letters" : "",
                "self.remaining_guesses" : 6,
                "self.has_ended" : False,
                "self.has_won" : False,
                "self.used_letters" : "",
                "self.own_word" : False,
                "self.user": "",
                "self.edit_word":  ""
                }
            }
        if ctx.author in self.dictionaries:
            self.dictionaries[ctx.author][ctx.author]['self.player'] = ctx.author.id
            self.dictionaries[ctx.author][ctx.author]["self.remaining_guesses"] = 6
            self.dictionaries[ctx.author][ctx.author]["self.chosen_word"] = ""
            self.dictionaries[ctx.author][ctx.author]["self.guessed_letters"] = ""
            self.dictionaries[ctx.author][ctx.author]["self.has_ended"] = False
            self.dictionaries[ctx.author][ctx.author]["self.has_won"] = False
            self.dictionaries[ctx.author][ctx.author]["self.used_letters"] = ""
            self.dictionaries[ctx.author][ctx.author]["self.own_word"] = False
            self.dictionaries[ctx.author][ctx.author]["self.user"] = ""
            self.dictionaries[ctx.author][ctx.author]["self.edit_word"] = ""
```

Basically every time a player plays a game they will get new values, if they are existing player those values get reset back to default. However it ends up me needing to call the dict over and over again. Is there a better way to implement this?

Thank You!

Comment: Look into object-oriented programming in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping how you manage your games, you have multiple ways of doing it:

- Using `enumerate`:

```py
reset_values = [ctx.author.id, "", "", 6, False, False, "", False, "", ""]
for count, key in enumerate(self.dictionaries[ctx.author].keys()):
    self.dictionaries[ctx.author][key] = reset_values[count]
```

- Using `zip`:

```py
reset_values = [ctx.author.id, "", "", 6, False, False, "", False, "", ""]
for key, value in zip(self.dictionaries[ctx.author].keys(), reset_values):
    self.dictionaries[ctx.author][key] = value
```

- Creating a blank model:

```py
blank_model = {
    "self.player": ctx.author.id,
    "self.chosen_word" : "",
    "self.guessed_letters" : "",
    "self.remaining_guesses" : 6,
    "self.has_ended" : False,
    "self.has_won" : False,
    "self.used_letters" : "",
    "self.own_word" : False,
    "self.user": "",
    "self.edit_word":  ""
}
self.dictionnaries[ctx.author] = blank_model
```

However, what you're doing is similar to [object-oriented programming](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) and I highly recommend you to use it. It will be way simpler to handle users and games than using dictionnaries to store data.

Comment: Thank you for this, i will have to check out OOP as im not really sure how to implement it into my project atm.